# cannot find module 'next/router' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

Currently having some problems with my NextJS app.

I get the error below. Which is really weird, because my code runs perfectly with no errors.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
// Cannot find module 'next/router' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

However, I get the error above in my IDE, this error is stopping my turbo build and yarn build commands to run, causing me to be unable to be able to push to production.

I have restarted my ts server, uninstalled next, updated to latest version and ran yarn to install everything again.

I've made an example repository on GitHub. https://github.com/MonkeeMan1/test

This is happening for all my next imports.
`Cannot find module 'next/router' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`
`Cannot find module 'next/link' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`
`Cannot find module 'next/image' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

Package.json
https://hatebin.com/ylujtdhtht

I have tried using moduleResolution `node`, as well as `node16`

`node` results in my local package `cachetesting` to not be found, so it is unable to be imported. And `node16` results in nextjs import errors.

Comment: it should be 'next/navigation', import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

Comment: Hi Tom Fan. Thank you for the response. But this unfortunately results in the same problem. Every import from `Next` results in the same `Cannot find module 'next/navigation' or its corresponding type declarations.`. I believe it may be an issue with ESM.

Comment: Have you checked that all dependencies are installed by using `npm install check-dependencies --save-dev` in the root directory of the repo? -- The example works fine and and `import { useRouter } from "next/router";` doesn't produce an error when used inside `apps/pages/index.tsx`.

Comment: Hi @Christopher

The example on my Github does error for me. I have definitely installed all dependencies as my code successfully runs. It only fails when using `turbo build`. However, I still do get the issue of the red text on my imports, which my intelisense shows me before building.

I have tried your suggestion with running npm install check-dep... however the issue still persists.

 I use `yarn` and `turbo dev` to start/install the project dependencies. Sometimes the IDE doesn't update the intelisense so I would recommend restarting the ts server once done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is your `tsconfig.json`. The configuration isn't correct for a Next/React TS project.

Replace with this => https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/hello-world/tsconfig.json

==Solution==

After reading your comments I understand what you are trying to do better.

Here is how I got it to work.

**Step 1: Fix path of `nextjs.json`**

`apps/web/tsconfig.json`

```
"extends": "../../packages/tsconfig/nextjs.json",
```

---

**Step 2: Fix `module` and `moduleResolution` in `nextjs.json`**

`packages/tsconfig/nextjs.json`

```
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

---

**Step 3: Fix `cache: *` to match package name**

`apps/web/package.json`

```
"cachetesting": "*",
```

---

**Step 4: Add main to `package.json` for cache**

`packages/cache/package.json`

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
```

Not sure if you have seen [this link](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages), but this helped me debug

Comment: Hi @rguarascia.ts, part of the reason for moving away from default next tsconfig is that it doesn't allow me to import local packages in my monorepo. I have a custom package in my mono repo called `cache` and when using default nextjs configs it says `cache' is declared but its value is never read.`. Only when using `node16` am I able to import this package.

I use the same config across my whole monorepo, its only nextjs which is doesn't work in.
I have linked an example github repository in my question which includes an brief 
 example of my monorepo, and demonstrates the problems I have

Comment: It is good to note, that this does resolve the issue with the next imports. But just means I cannot import my own local packages in my monorepo.

Comment: @kamza thanks for the insight, see above with solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been an issue I have for so long, I appreciate your help alot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct module for your version of Next.js.

Next.js went from pages to app from version 12 to version 13.

'next/router' is only for use in /pages, whereas 'next/navigation' is for use in /app

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating